# i have a so file and i want to call a function within the so file from lua

Tags: c, lua

I have a simple c file as below which I have compiled and converted into an so file and transported the .so file into another directory.

```
test.c

#include<stdio.h>
void disp()
{
  printf("This is comming from .so file");
}
int main()
{
  disp();
  return 0;
}
```

To compile gcc -shared -o libtest.so -fPIC test.c

Now I have a lua file . I want to access the disp() function.how should i do that?i tried the following way but did not work. any suggestions??thanks

```
test.lua

test={}
function test.init()
return disp()
end

return test
```

now when i do a require i get the following error

```
 Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
    require "test"
    test.init()
    ./test.lua:4: attempt to call global 'disp' (a nil value)
    stack traceback:
        ./test.lua:4: in function 'init'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Use `package.loadlib`

Comment: That's now how lua modules work. You need to (1) not make a `int main()` function (2) make a `luaopen_X` function with an appropriate signature, so that lua can find it. Read the docs.